# After installing Oracle Java 8 how can you update?

Tags: java, ppa, oracle

There is an oracle-jdk8-installer dir in /var/cache/

There is a /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle dir

How can I update to the latest plugins and jre stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed Oracle Java from [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

They did not update java to the latest release yet. You can do it manually.

1. Download JDK from [Oracle Site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). You will need Linux x86 tar.gz file for 32-bit Ubuntu or x64 tar.gz file for 64-bit.
2. Copy this file to `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer`.
3. Extract contents of the tar.gz archive to `/usr/lib/java-8-oracle` directory.

This is enough if you previously had Java installed from that repository.

I hope they will update it soon.